# How to get a taxi on Prague streets?

Tags: taxis, prague

I wanted to get a taxi near Centrum Chodov (a shopping mall), but couldn't see any taxi stand around. I waited on the street for about 15 minutes, no luck. Then I got into Centrum Chodov and asked the information desk to call a taxi. The problem was resolved for this time, but later I encountered the same problem again on a central street.

Now I see that getting a taxi on the streets is [not recommended](https://www.tasteofprague.com/pragueblog/taxi-in-prague), however my problem is not related to any kind of fraud. I just have difficulties finding a taxi.

> - Never get a taxi in front of the train or bus station.
> - Actually, never get a taxi on the street.

Can't we get a taxi on the streets in Prague? If I'm not able to call (via phone), what should I do?

Comment: Why not use Uber?

Comment: @JonathanReez Sometimes I have no access to internet.

Comment: A cheap EU SIM card would resolve all your troubles. It would certainly be cheaper than hailing street cabs.

Comment: @JonathanReez I'll try next time.

Comment: Didn't a problem getting one but I got ripped off. Never did it again.

Comment: Why not using public tranport? It should be much faster, considering how much time you loose hunting for taxi. Taxi is something people usually use for fixed terms, like going to airport, than a receptionist should call it for you.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo Since the traffic density was reasonable in Prague, I would expect taxis to be fast enough. I will keep in mind for my further travels to Prague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend getting a EU Sim card primarily for data connectivity. That way you can book taxi online.

Most train or bus stations have free wifi. You can use that to book taxi online.

Uber is pretty reliable in Prague. Choose Uber pop for the cheapest Uber ride. If you know the time and place when you'll need a taxi schedule a Uber ride.

Other option is Modry Andel (ble anglel) - https://modryandel.cz/en

Hope that helps!